# uicollection view inside uitableview always show 0 array.lenth and never load data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, collectionview

I am facing an issue in my project basically I want to use  uicollectionview inside uitableview but it always shows 0 arrays .count in numberOfItemsInSection of collectionview here is the code of collection view inside tableview cell

```
      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: 
        Int) -> Int {
        print(experience_array_skill.count)// always show 0 
        return experience_array_skill.count
          
         }

       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: 
                IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
              let cell = collects.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "shorlist_exp_cell", 
         for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! shorlist_exp_cell
           cell.btn1.text = self.experience_array_skill[indexPath.row].experience_in
        
            cell.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
            cell.clipsToBounds = true
                   
                return cell
           }
        
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: 
       IndexPath) {
                
        }
```

***my JSON***

```
      {
       "message": "candidate job listing",
        "status": true,
        "data": [
       {
        "id": 1,
        "company_name_shown_job": "xyz company",
        "job_title": "Android Developer",
        "job_description": null,
        "experience_tags": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "employer_job_post_id": 1,
                "experience_in": "Android"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "employer_job_post_id": 1,
                "experience_in": "Php"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "company_name_shown_job": "Abc company",
        "job_title": "Web Developer",
        "job_description": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,laborum.</p>",
        "experience_tags": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "employer_job_post_id": 2,
                "experience_in": "Swift"

            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "employer_job_post_id": 2,
                "experience_in": "Java"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

in the above JSON data is the array of my uitableview whereas

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is this array **experience_array_skill** doesn't contain any value. How are you adding data to experience_array_skill array Since the array has no value you are getting 0 as the value of count. So maybe once look at that part and if you can't find it, post that section of code. The above code seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

the data you have been passing from tableview to **experience_array_skill** array is always nil hence you are getting the 0 on the count. Check the code where you are passing the data to your **experience_array_skill** array.